# Convert Crt and Key to Pfx

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-8.5

I made a new certificate with ZeroSSL and now I have a crt file and a Key file for the domain. I'm using no tools because I would like to get the process runing first by hand.

To use it with IIS 8.5 must I have to convert this to a pfx file? How to do this without OpenSSL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Save certificate and key files with identical names in the same folder (cert.cer and cert.key, for example) and use `certutil`:

```
certutil -mergepfx cert.cer cert.pfx
```

and enter PFX password.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. It was tricky that the .key file needed the same name in the same folder to work. Even though it's not a parameter of certutil
folder:
{{sitename}}.crt
{{siteName}}.key